# Redirect two files with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

this is my scenario. My application urls are showed like this:

```
example.com/index.php/article/whatever/here
```

in order to remove the index.php from url I have put this in my .htaccess and works fine:

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now, my problem is that I have include and admin.php like this:

```
example.com/admin.php/manage/whatever/here
```

And I don't know how to remove the admin.php from url without make conflics with the index.php because I have tried this and a 500 Internal Server Error is showed:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin.php/$1 [L]
```

**EDIT**

Another try was this and nothing, because a 404 error is showed:

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^/(.*?)/(.*) /$1/$2 [L]
```

ALL my urls should have several parameteres as requiered:

```
example.com/this/is/a/large/url/because/is/requiered
```

EDIT 2:

I have create two rules, each rule alone works fine!!! but both can't work together:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /admin.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: you cant.. how should apache know which one you want if you present him the same regexp for both? (take all and add it to.. index AND admin.php)

Comment: you are right, but how can I implement the AND condition here?

Comment: no you dont understand your QUERY is the same for both urls.. `^(.*)$` how can apache now if its for index.php or admin.php? the 500error just says you have the same regexp more then once. extend the regexp and include index.php for the first, and admin.php for the second rule into the regexp source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^admin/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Then at least test this with:

```
http://www.example.com/some/url
http://www.example.com/admin/some/url
```

Comment: Ok, now looks better, my index.php was removed and the urls works fine. But no the same for urls that start with /admin/blabla ..404 I think that we are so close now

Comment: I have remove the line RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^admin/(.*)$ [NC] and the overwrite the admin rule like this RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /admin.php/$1 [L] and Works perfect!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly modify your rewrite rule to capture the first part of the path, and use it in the replacement. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*?)/(.*) /$1/$2 [L]
```

Basically the `()` create a capturing group, so anything between the first two `/` will be captured as `$1` and anything after that will be captured as `$2`

Note that you can also change your rewrite conditions, if you only want this replacement to apply to `index.php` and `admin.php`

Comment: but wouldn't that require him to keep index, admin and foobar in the url? ex: example.com/index/article/whatever/here or example.com/admin/this

Comment: @sixeightzero Yes, it would. But I don't know the full details of the application and all the possible paths. You could also modify the rewrite conditions to check specifically for which instances you wanted to replace.

Comment: I have edited the post with another details mencioned. But it not works yet

Comment: sorry, I had an error... change the first `$` to a `*`... it should be `RewriteRule ^/(.*?)/(.*) /$1/$2 [L]`

Comment: @BrianGlaz, I have change that symbol and the 404 error persist in both cases

Comment: Ok guys, How about to append the "admin" after domain like this example.com/admin/articles/or/whatever for admin.pphp request ??

Comment: In your question you specified the paths as `/admin.php/` and now your example is just `/admin/`. Which one is correct??

Comment: My original question is how to remove the index.php and admin.php from urls. But, it turns so complicated, so according to aswers above we could apply another solution if removing this files is to much conflictive